# Multiple Handlers for Websocket Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, websocket

Is that possible that we can have multiple handlers (onmessage method) for same webcocket session?
In the below code there is only one onmessage method to handle a message from the client. 
But is there any possibility that we can have multiple onmessage handler methods for same websocket session ?

Code:

```
    var url = window.location.href;
    var arr = url.split("/");
    var redirectURL = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2];
    var wsURL = redirectURL.replace('http','ws');
    var ws = new WebSocket(wsURL+'/abc');
    ws.onopen = function(event) {
        var data = '{"userId":' + sessionStorage.getItem('userID') + '}';
        ws.send((data));
    };

    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
        var msg = event.data;
        console.info('Push Message : ' + msg);
        Ext.toast({
             html: msg,
             title: 'Alert',
             align: 'br',
             autoShow : true
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `WebSocket` object supports `.addEventListener()` so, you can do this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var arr = url.split("/");
var redirectURL = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2];
var wsURL = redirectURL.replace('http','ws');
var ws = new WebSocket(wsURL+'/abc');
ws.addEventListener("open", function(event) {
    var data = '{"userId":' + sessionStorage.getItem('userID') + '}';
    ws.send((data));
});

ws.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    var msg = event.data;
    console.info('Push Message : ' + msg);
    Ext.toast({
         html: msg,
         title: 'Alert',
         align: 'br',
         autoShow : true
    });

});

// some other listener for incoming messages
ws.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Actually I'm working on Extjs multi tab application and all the tabs have their own separate viewport. So now when ever I open a new tab, I've to create a new websocket session. so is there any possibility so that I'll create only one session for all tabs in this scenario. Because creating multiple websocket session resources are difficult, as per the maintenance perspective.

Comment: @user2508337 - It would be very complicated to create only one webSocket for multiple tabs and have them all share that one connection.  You would have to do inter-window messages between all the tabs, make sure one tab has the open connection and all other windows send/receive message from that master window.  Then, if the master tab is closed, another one would have to create a new connection and become the new master.  It's very complicated and likely much, much simpler to just have each tab have it's own webSocket connection.