# Intercept WebSocket messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, electron

With ajax requests it can be done with this code:

```
let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.lastXhr = '';
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
  this.addEventListener('load', function() {
    window.lastXhr = this.responseText;
  });
  return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

`lastXhr` variable will hold the last response.

But how can this be achieved for websockets too?

Comment: I can listen to websocket messages through controlling the `MessageEvent` class >:D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> you would need to make this wrapper as soon as possible

@brunoff you're correct in that you can always use your functions before a server's by puppet window logic, **or** you could just hijack the `data` from the `MessageEvent` itself:

```js
function listen(fn){
  fn = fn || console.log;

  let property = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MessageEvent.prototype, "data");
  
  const data = property.get;

  // wrapper that replaces getter
  function lookAtMessage() {

    let socket = this.currentTarget instanceof WebSocket;

    if (!socket) {
      return data.call(this);
    }

    let msg = data.call(this);

    Object.defineProperty(this, "data", { value: msg } ); //anti-loop
    fn({ data: msg, socket:this.currentTarget, event:this });
    return msg;
  }
  
  property.get = lookAtMessage;
  
  Object.defineProperty(MessageEvent.prototype, "data", property);
}

listen( ({data}) => console.log(data))
```

You can try putting in the code and running it in the console on [this page](https://javascript.info/websocket) and then running their WebSocket example.

Comment: The only solution that works...

Comment: @The Bomb Squad congratulations!!! You deserve it!

Comment: Elegant approach

Comment: what is this magic, don't understand this enough to know why it works but it's the only solution that works for me, thank you!

quick question - does this intercept only received message or also sent message on the websocket?

Comment: @Jin it would intercept received message and then in the function you pass into `listen`, you can have `event=>event.socket.addEventListener('message',forIncomingMessages)`. In terms of getting the websocket object from a sent message, view the **second** snippet in [brunoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70239957/10697213)

Answer (score 10):

To intercept the messages, you will have to spy on the `onmessage = fn` and `addEventListener("message", fn)` calls.

To be able to modify the `onmessage` we have to override the global `WebSocket` in the first place. The below is intercepting the incoming messages, but in a similar way you can spy on the `send` method to intercept the outgoing messages (the ones sent by the client to the server).

I tested this on a page using Firebase and it works nicely, but you have to initialize it before the other scripts making sure that the websocket library (it can be socket.io, ws, etc) is using the overridden `WebSocket` constructor.

#### Spy the Incoming Messages *and* modify the `data`

Eventually you can **override the `data` before calling the real message listener** – this becomes handy if you do not have control over the page functionality and want to inject your own data in the message listener.

```
const OriginalWebsocket = window.WebSocket
const ProxiedWebSocket = function() {
  console.log("Intercepting web socket creation")

  const ws = new OriginalWebsocket(...arguments)

  const originalAddEventListener = ws.addEventListener
  const proxiedAddEventListener = function() {
    if (arguments[0] === "message") {
      const cb = arguments[1]
      arguments[1] = function() {
        // Here you can get the actual data from the incoming messages
        // Here you can even change the data before calling the real message listener
        Object.defineProperty(e, "data", { value: 'your injected data' })
        console.log("intercepted", arguments[0].data)
        return cb.apply(this, arguments)
      }
    }
    return originalAddEventListener.apply(this, arguments)
  }
  ws.addEventListener = proxiedAddEventListener

  Object.defineProperty(ws, "onmessage", {
    set(func) {
      return proxiedAddEventListener.apply(this, [
        "message",
        func,
        false
      ]);
    }
  });
  return ws;
};

window.WebSocket = ProxiedWebSocket;
```

If you do not need to modify the data, you can follow the second part of the answer.

#### Spy the Incoming messages without modifying the data

If you want to **listen for messages only, without overriding the data**, things are simpler:

```
const OriginalWebsocket = window.WebSocket
const ProxiedWebSocket = function() {
  const ws = new OriginalWebsocket(...arguments)
  ws.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
    // Only intercept
    console.log(e.data)
  })
  return ws;
};
window.WebSocket = ProxiedWebSocket;
```

#### Spy the Outgoing Messages

In a very similar way, you can proxy the `send` method which is used to send data to the server.

```
const OriginalWebsocket = window.WebSocket
const ProxiedWebSocket = function() {
  const ws = new OriginalWebsocket(...arguments)
  const originalSend = ws.send
  const proxiedSend = function() {
    console.log("Intercepted outgoing ws message", arguments)
    // Eventually change the sent data
    // arguments[0] = ...
    // arguments[1] = ...
    return originalSend.apply(this, arguments)
  }
  ws.send = proxiedSend
  return ws;
};
window.WebSocket = ProxiedWebSocket;
```

Feel free to ask any questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: to `modify the message data` you would have to make `arguments[0]` a completely different object since `arguments[0].data='someFakeText'` wouldn't do it

Comment: @TheBombSquad Overriding the entire argument would not be really recommended because that is a `MessageEvent` instance. Keeping the reference, and overriding only the `data` property would be smoother.

Comment: @IonicăBizău I forgot that u can just `Object.defineProperty` the data key into the instance.. but yea a simple `arguments[0].data="someOtherValue"` alone won't override it

Answer (score 2):

### Intro

The question/bounty/op is specifically asking for a reputable source.
Instead of rolling a custom solution, my proposal is that a known proven library should be used  - that has been used, audited, forked, and in general used by the community and that is hosted on github.

[image]

The second option is to roll your own (though not recommended) and there are many exccelent answers on how to do it involving the `addEventListener`

### wshook

[Wshook](https://github.com/skepticfx/wshook#easily-intercept-and-modify-websocket-requests-and-message-events) is a library (hosted on github) that allows to easily intercept and modify WebSocket requests and message events. It has been starred and forked multiple times.

Disclaimer: I don't have any relationship with the specific project.**strong text**

Example:

```
wsHook.before = function(data, url, wsObject) {
    console.log("Sending message to " + url + " : " + data);
}

// Make sure your program calls `wsClient.onmessage` event handler somewhere.
wsHook.after = function(messageEvent, url, wsObject) {
    console.log("Received message from " + url + " : " + messageEvent.data);
    return messageEvent;
}
```

From the documentation, you will find:

> **wsHook.before - function(data, url, wsObject)**:
>
> Invoked just before
> calling the actual WebSocket's send() method.
>
> This method must return data which can be modified as well.

> **wsHook.after - function(event, url, wsObject):**
>
> Invoked just after
> receiving the MessageEvent from the WebSocket server and before
> calling the WebSocket's onmessage Event Handler.

### Websocket addEventListener

The WebSocket object supports `.addEventListener()`.
Please see: [Multiple Handlers for Websocket Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210534/multiple-handlers-for-websocket-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

In a solution similar to yours, where the `window.XMLHttpRequest` was replaced with a wrapped version that feeds `window.lastXhr`, we replace `window.WebSockets` with a wrapped version that feeds `window.WebSocketMessages` with all messages and timestamps received from all websockets created after this script.

```js
window.watchedWebSockets = [];
window.WebSocketMessages = [];

function WebSocketAttachWatcher(websocket) {
    websocket.addEventListener("message", (event)=>window.WebSocketMessages.push([event.data,Date.now()]));
    window.watchedWebSockets.push(websocket);
}

// here we replace WebSocket with a wrapped one, that attach listeners on 
window.WebSocketUnchanged = window.WebSocket;
window.WebSocket = function(...args) {
    const websocket = new window.WebSocketUnchanged(...args);
    WebSocketAttachWatcher(websocket);
    return websocket;
}
```

Differently from your XMLRequest case, the websocket may already exist. If you need garanties that all websockets would be catched then you would need to make this wrapper as soon as possible. If you just can't, there's an not so good trick to capture already existing websockets once they send a message:

```js
// here we detect existing websockets on send event... not so trustable
window.WebSocketSendUnchanged = window.WebSocketUnchanged.prototype.send;
window.WebSocket.prototype.send = function(...args) {
    console.log("firstsend");
    if (!(this in window.watchedWebSockets))
        WebSocketAttachWatcher(this);
    this.send = window.WebSocketSendUnchanged; // avoid passing here again on next send
    window.WebSocketSendUnchanged.call(this, ...args);
}
```

It is not so trustable since if they don't send but receive they will stay unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using nodejs then you can use `socket.io`

```
yarn add socket.io
```

after installation, you can use the [middleware](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#registering-a-middleware) of `socket.io`

```
io.use(async (socket, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await fetchUser(socket);
    socket.user = user;
  } catch (e) {
    next(new Error("unknown user"));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble getting the above solutions to work (like I did):

Apparently the WebSocket object is now a JavaScript class instead of a plain old prototype, and some modern websites really don't like it if you override the class and turn it back into a prototype.

Thankfully, you can just create a new class that extends the old one and override it!

```
window.WebSocketUnchanged = window.WebSocket;


class CustomWebSocket extends window.WebSocket {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);

        this.onmessageListenerCallbackOriginal = function() {};

        super.onmessage = function(event) {
            //Runs as soon as a WebSocket message is received
            if (this.interceptReceivedMessage(event)) {
                this.onmessageListenerCallbackOriginal(event);
            }
        }


        Object.defineProperty(this, "onmessage", {
            set(func) {
                //Save this event handler in our own variable
                //but don't let it touch the original WebSocket
                //as we want to run our own code before running
                //the onmessage event handler we are given
                this.onmessageListenerCallbackOriginal = func;
            }
        });


    }

    onmessage(event) {
        console.log("onmessage was called but hasn't been overridden");
    }

    interceptReceivedMessage(event) {
        //Intercept the received message and do whatever you like with it
        console.log("Intercepted received message!");
        console.log(event);

        return true; //return true to allow the request to be received
    }

    send() {
        console.log(arguments);
        //Intercept the sent message and do whatever you like with it
        super.send(...arguments);
    }

    addEventListener(type, callback) {
        //Intercepts event handlers sent via addEventListener
        if (type == 'message') {
            super.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
                if (this.interceptReceivedMessage(event)) {
                    callback(event);
                }
            })
        } else {
            super.addEventListener(type, callback);
        }
    }


}

window.WebSocket = CustomWebSocket;



console.log("Finished adding interceptor to WebSocket");
```

Hope this helps!