# JS function passed as an argument, how can it be modified?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension that injects a script in a page that replaces WebSocket, for the sole purpose of intercepting messages from the server in order to log them.

For sending it's easy as WebSocket has a `.send()` method that you can override. But when receiving it's not so simple.

So I'm currently in a point where the original application is setting socket.onmessage() with its own function. I'm intercepting that function (which is passed as an argument) inside the prototype, but I can't modify it or it breaks. Replacing it would move its dependancies out of scope of the original function which is defined initially in an anonymous function (in which the WebSocket is instanced).

Is there a way to perform such logging by modifying the callback which is passed to the prototype?

```js
        var WebSocket = function (url, protocols) {
            'native';
            if (window.location.protocol === 'https:' &&
                url.lastIndexOf('ws:', 0) === 0) {
                // Just in case, plain text WS cannot be used on HTTPS webpages.
                // So we just trigger an exception.
                var ws = new Wrapped(url, protocols);
                if (ws) {
                    ws.close();
                }
            }
            
            Object.defineProperties(this, {
               'onmessage': {
                    get: function () {
                        return getWrappedProperty(this, 'onmessage', null);
                    },
                    set: function (value) { //<------ value is the callback function here and it gets called every time a messages arrives via WebSocket
                        setWrappedProperty(this, 'onmessage', value);
                    }
                },
```

```js
        var getWrappedProperty = function (wrapper, prop, defaultValue) {
            var wrapped = map.get(wrapper);
            if (!wrapped) {
                return defaultValue;
            }
            
            if (wrapped instanceof Wrapped) {
                return wrapped[prop];
            }
            
            return wrapped.properties.hasOwnProperty(prop) ?
                wrapped.properties[prop] :
                defaultValue;
        };
        
        /**
         * Sets a value of the specified property.
         *
         * @param wrapper   Wrapper instance
         * @param prop      Property name
         * @param value     Value to set
         */
        var setWrappedProperty = function (wrapper, prop, value) {
            if (value instanceof Function) {
                value = value.bind(wrapper);
            }
            
            var wrapped = map.get(wrapper);
            if (!wrapped) {
                return;
            }
            
            if (wrapped instanceof Wrapped) {
                wrapped[prop] = value;
            } else {
                wrapped.properties[prop] = value;
            }
        };
```

Comment: This might be useful -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205816/intercept-websocket-messages    If you go to -> https://en.js.cx/article/websocket/chat/ and post the code in that question into the console it logs all the websocket data.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly breaks and why you can't modify it, but generally you don't need to care about onmessage function at all as you can simply add one yourself:  wsobj.addEventListener('message', yourFn).